# Question about existence of uniformly continuous homeomorphism from a non empty open set to $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

This question was asked in my real analysis quiz and I was not able to solve it.

> Let $U$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R} $. Suppose that there exists a uniformly continuous homeomorphism $ h: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ . Show that $U=\mathbb{ R} $.

I thought of assuming that $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R} $ and then trying to find a contradiction. But I am confused on what property I should use and unable to find a contradiction.

Comment: This posting should be quite informative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804009/uniformly-continuous-homeomorphism-from-a-subset-of-mathbbr-to-mathbbr#comment7840343_3804009.

Comment: Since $U$ is homoemorphic to $\mathbb R$, it has to be an interval.

Comment: I have posted an A to this on the link given by @ΑΘΩ above, which had none, and is the same problem except that it is a request for proof-verification, while I merely posted a solution, so I might get some flak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U(\subset\Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb R$ are homeomorphic, $U$ is an open interval. Suppose that it is an interval of the form $(a,b)$, with $a\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$ ($b\in\Bbb R$ or $b=\infty$). there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$x,y\in(a,b)\wedge|x-y|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<1.$$But it follows from that $f$ maps bounded sets into bounded sets. So, if $c\in(a,b)$, $f\bigl((a,c)\bigr)$ is bounded. On the other hand, $f$ is injective and continuous, and therefore it is monotonic. So, you can have $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=\infty$ or $\lim_{xto b}f(x)=-\infty$, but you can't have both. Therefore, either $f$ cannot take arbitrarily large values or it cannot take arbitrarily small values. In either case, it cannot be a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Carlos Santos Can you please tell which result you are using to prove that U must be an open interval?

Comment: @User Since $U\subset\Bbb R$ and it is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, which is connected, $U$ is connected too, and therefore it is an interval. If it is, say, an interval of the form $[a,b)$ (where $b$ can be a real number greater than $a$ or $\infty$), then $U\setminus\{a\}$ is connected. But, for any $x\in\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ is not connected. So, $U$ would not be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. By the same argument, $U$ cannot be an interval of the type $(a,b]$ or of the type $[a,b]$. Therefore, it is an open interval.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $U$ is a disjoint union of open intervals. The existence of a homeomorphism $f$ with the real  line makes $U$ connected, so $U$ is  single open interval. Any continuous injection on an open interval is strictly monotonic. If $b <\infty$ the $f$ extends to $(a,b]$ by uniform continuity but then $f$ would be bounded above, a contradiciton. Similarly, $a =-\infty$.